# socket descriptor as a function argument

Tags: linux, sockets, file-descriptor

Can I pass a file socket descriptor as a function argument, i.e.

```
void mysend(int fd, uint8_t *data, size_t len)
{
   ...
   sendto(fd, ...);
   ...
}

int main()
{
    int fd = socket(...);
    uint8_t data[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    mysend(fd, data, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

I have existing API that does that. I was wondering if there could be issues that are hidden by writing code in this manner

Comment: It would help if you didn't name your function the same as the standard `send(2)` library function, especially since it has a different signature. Call your function, `my_send`, `sendy` or `send2019`.

Comment: @mosvy Got it. Just fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can absolutely do that. For example the libc does it:

```
ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
ssize_t read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count);
ssize_t sendto(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, ...);
```

These functions can take a socket descriptor as first argument.

A remark on your code: before the `return`, do not forget to `close(fd)`.

It is recommended that you cleanly separate the functions that create, use and close the file descriptor.

Comment: There's no need to `close()` anything just before returning from `main()`.

Comment: @mosvy Indeed, but it is a good practice to `close()`, because when the code evolves and people start copying-pasting code and relocating code fragments in other functions, then the missing `close()` will become a bug.

Comment: An another reason for call close(): It may fail. When it fails, some data may be lost, and you probably want to tell that to user of the program.